# Postgres Replication - On premise to Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, database-replication

I have a project that requires an on premises PostgreSQL database to be replicated to an Azure Flexible Server for Postgres in real time. I'm not interested in any failure over mechanisms, just the actual replication.

I have looked at PostgreSQL's built in streaming replication, however it doesn't look like it would be possible to configure the slave server in Azure.

I've also looked at Azure's database migration tool, but its rather expensive for online migration and technically is not the use case its designed for.

Does anybody know of any alternatives that could be used to do the job?

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary that you be using exactly "Azure Flexible Server for Postgres"? You could just rent an underlying OS from Azure, and then install and run community PostgreSQL on that and have it be in streaming replica mode.

Comment: Its a good idea, my only concern would be no automatic backups, maintenance and other built in features. I'd also have to look at costing. I think its a good option to keep in the back pocket.